# Certificates and private key files fail on loading but works well when directly used for communication in FIPS mode

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography, certificate

Certificates when used for communication:

Below command works fine.

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/root/PyCharmProjects/ese/lib/ese/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}  curl -v -k  --cert cert-test.crt --key private-key.pem --pass o7gpIToCCqf2ynwV2UkieV9E6z3Tq5KZexXc

Certificates when loaded :

> cat cryptography_sample.py

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat._oid import NameOID
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization, hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa

import os
import socket

cert_file="/tmp/cert-test.crt"
priv_file="/tmp/private-key.pem"
passphrase="o7gpIToCCqf2ynwV2UkieV9E6z3Tq5KZexXc"

def verify_privatekey_and_certs_for_pkcs(private_key: bytes = None,
                                         pass_phrase: bytes = None,
                                         client_cert: bytes = None):
    try:
        if client_cert:
            print(f"client crt: {client_cert}")
            print(f"client crt type: {type(client_cert)}")
            x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(client_cert, default_backend())
        else:
            print(f"client priv: {private_key}")
            print(f"client priv type: {type(private_key)}")
            print(f"client pass phrase: {pass_phrase}")
            serialization.load_pem_private_key(private_key, pass_phrase, default_backend())
    except Exception as e: 
            print(f"Incorrect cert/private key passed, reason : {e} ")

try:
    print("load private key and validate")
    with open(priv_file, "rb") as key_data:
        verify_privatekey_and_certs_for_pkcs(private_key=key_data.read(),pass_phrase=bytes(passphrase,'utf-8'))
    print("load certs and validate")
    with open(cert_file, "rb") as cert_data:
        verify_privatekey_and_certs_for_pkcs(client_cert=cert_data.read())
except Exception as ex:
    print(f"Failed to verify certificates : {ex}")
```

Output:

Incorrect cert/private key passed, reason : ('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [<OpenSSLError(code=50856204, lib=6, reason=524556, reason_text=unsupported)>, <OpenSSLError(code=293601387, lib=35, reason=107, reason_text=key gen error)>, <OpenSSLError(code=50856204, lib=6, reason=524556, reason_text=unsupported)>, <OpenSSLError(code=293601387, lib=35, reason=107, reason_text=key gen error)>])
load certs and validate

serialization.load_pem_private_key is throwing the above error.

In the failure case, pem_read_bio_privatekey function in backend.py(cryptography )is returning NULL.

Openssl version: 3.0.12

Python version: 3.12.0

Cryptography: 41.0.5

Comment: As the error message indicates, the problem may have one of the following causes *...incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type...* Can you post a non-productive test key (of the same format, encoding and encryption) including test passphrase? The curl statement alone is a bit thin as presumably different formats are supported.